# Cloudwatch Alarm for Aurora Data Dump Automation to S3 Bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, automation, cloudwatch-alarms

I need your advice on something that I'm working on as a part of my work.

I'm working on automating the Aurora Dump to S3 bucket every midnight. As a part of it, I have created a ec2 instance that generates the dump and I have written a python script using boto3 which moves the dump to S3 bucket every night.

I need to intimate a list of developers if the data dump doesn't take place for some reason.

As of now, I'm posting a message to SNS topic which notifies the developers if the backup doesn't happen. But I need to do this with Cloudwatch and I'm not sure how to do it.

Your help will be much appreciated. ! Thanks!

Comment: Probably you could create some custom metric with 0 - no error, 1 - beckup error and then based your CW alarm on that. But what's wrong with using SNS?

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. I did that and it's working without any issues now. I need to integrate cloudwatch with other projects as well and wanted to see if that can be done.

Comment: Glad it worked out:-)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom metric to which I have attached a Cloudwatch alarm and it gets triggered if there's an issue in data backup process.